# Define a new type of time in golang

Tags: time, go

I want to have a struct like this:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    DateJoined time
}
```

But this struct will not compile, because there is no type `time`, isn't it?
Should I alternatively use a `string` and insert the time / date information there?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`time` isn't a type. `time.Time` is. See the package docs for the types: http://golang.org/pkg/time/

```
import time

type Person struct {
    Name string
    DateJoined time.Time
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you need to import time package and of course you use time.Time
btw, it returned error when I defined my own type as below with similar reason to you. And, someone helped me to do cast (ex. mytime(time.Now()).

```
type mytime time.Time
```

You can make your own package and import always so that all your own type in your convenience